# Regex: Grafana Variables convert hyphen separated IPs to Dot separated IPs

Tags: regex, go, grafana, prometheus, re2

I am trying to created a variable in Grafana using a custom query to scan the nodes in EKS cluster. Currently the node variable is stored as "hyphen" separated strings (ex. 10-109-22-102); i intend it to be reported as "dot" separated strings (ex. 10.109.22.102). Is this even possible by regex?

Grafana [variables](https://grafana.com/docs/reference/templating/#variables) support creating of live variables by scraping a given metric and then extracting a value in the reported metric using regex. I am currently scraping a metric:

> kube_node_info{container_runtime_version="docker://18.6.1",endpoint="http",instance="10.11.111.111:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",kernel_version="xxxxx",kubelet_version="xxxx",kubeproxy_version="xxxx",namespace="infra",node="ip-10-11-111-111.us-sdlls-as.compute.internal",os_image="Amazon
>   Linux
>   2",pod="prometheus-operator-kube-state-metrics-sdfgsjdkgl-saldjl",service="prometheus-operator-kube-state-metrics"}

I am currently using regex: `/.*node="ip-([^"]*).us-*/` to extract the "hyphen" separated IPs. I have also tried using other match groups ex: `([\d]{2,3})-([\d]{2,3})-([\d]{2,3})-([\d]{2,3})` however this returns only first match-group in grafana (in this case `10`) as the only option.

Expected output should be:

```
10.11.111.111
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The actual intent was to capture the IP of the instance and list all of them as a dynamic variable via a query and then enable all the node metrics via the IPs. This was a bad approach since lot of prometheus node-metrics are exported with label `node=ip-XX-XX-XXX-XXX-<region>-.compute.internal` (where XX are digits). Also grafana variables reports match of only the 1st sub-group - ideally it should be all the subgroups.

However, even if i were to capture the subgroup say XX.XX.XXX.XXX this would mean for every metric that I need to capture and graph I would need to address for matches for all the IPs in the EKS nodes - this is not possible especially if we want to enable "All" variable in which grafana replaces the variable call with regex of all the variables matches. Ex. if my k8s node had following IPs:
* 10.10.0.1
* 10.10.0.2
* 10.10.0.3
and I call this variable as Node
Grafana will list following variables:
* All
* 10.10.0.1
* 10.10.0.2
* 10.10.0.3
On selecting `All` grafana will do replace of $Node to `./*(10.10.0.1|10.10.0.2|10.10.0.3)*/` However if i had a Query for getting the node info : `kube_pod_info{node=~"$Node"}` -> this would fail because node name is in a different format we may try and solve it by using `label_replace` but again we cannot address using `$Node` in case `All` variable is used.

Conclusion : use the variable `$Node` (i.e. 
* ip-10-10-0-1.us-sdlls-as.compute.internal
* ip-10-10-0-2.us-sdlls-as.compute.internal
* ip-10-10-0-3.us-sdlls-as.compute.internal
) - *as-is* this would make all other panels much more convenient and easy to configure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the one you have designed should be working fine:

#### Test

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)([0-9]{2,3})-([0-9]{2,3})-([0-9]{2,3})-([0-9]{2,3})`)
    var str = `kube_node_info{container_runtime_version="docker://18.6.1",endpoint="http",instance="10.11.111.111:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",kernel_version="xxxxx",kubelet_version="xxxx",kubeproxy_version="xxxx",namespace="infra",node="ip-10-11-111-111.us-sdlls-as.compute.internal",os_image="Amazon Linux 2",pod="prometheus-operator-kube-state-metrics-sdfgsjdkgl-saldjl",service="prometheus-operator-kube-state-metrics" 

kube_node_info{container_runtime_version="docker://18.6.1",endpoint="http",instance="10.11.111.111:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",kernel_version="xxxxx",kubelet_version="xxxx",kubeproxy_version="xxxx",namespace="infra",node="ip-10-11-111-111.us-sdlls-as.compute.internal",os_image="Amazon Linux 2",pod="prometheus-operator-kube-state-metrics-sdfgsjdkgl-saldjl",service="prometheus-operator-kube-state-metrics" 

`
    var substitution = "$1.$2.$3.$4"
    
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(str, substitution))
}
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DCR9XO/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/DCR9XO/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Answer (score -1):

Your regex must work fine. However, the character sets are redundant since you are only using digits per set. Hence, they can be removed:

`(\d{2,3})-(\d{2,3})-(\d{2,3})-(\d{2,3})`

The captured data can then be substituted as:

`$1.$2.$3.$4`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fbrsjg/1)